# Cannot import dependency even after declaring it in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm starting a new project using Kotlin/Native. Everything works great, but now I've decided that I want the ImmutableDoubleArray class from guava. So I have included the dependency in my build.gradle.kts file and I tried to import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableDoubleArray

Unfortunately, now the build fails with the error message "Unresolved reference: com"

It seems as if the dependency is detected correctly (as gradle downloads the corresponding jar file), but somehow I can't reference it in my code. Any ideas?

I'm on gradle-8.4 and I'm currently not yet using an IDE. (Coding in emacs...) I started the build from the command line using `gradle --refresh-dependencies clean build`, but that doesn't help either. I even deleted my ~/.gradle directory and let grade download everything from scratch, which didn't help.

Everything works well with `kotlinx.collections.immutable.*`:

```
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.* // works
import com.google.common.primitives.ImmutableDoubleArray // doesn't, undefined reference: com
```

Here's my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("java-library")
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.9.20"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // 1. Use Guava in your implementation only:
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre")

    // 2. Use Guava types in your public API:
    //api("com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre")    
}

kotlin {

    jvm("jvm") {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "21"
            }
        }
    }

    linuxX64("linux")
    mingwX64("windows")

    targets.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget> {
        binaries {
        sharedLib {
        baseName = if(name == "windows") "libnative" else "native"
        }
    }
    }

    sourceSets {
        get("commonMain").apply {
        dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.6")
            implementation("com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre")
        }
        }
        get("commonTest").apply {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test"))
        }
        }
        get("windowsMain").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonMain"])
        }
        get("windowsTest").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonTest"])
        }
        get("linuxMain").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonMain"])
        }
        get("linuxTest").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonTest"])
        }
        get("jvmMain").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonMain"])
        }
        get("jvmTest").apply {
        dependsOn(sourceSets["commonTest"])
        }
    }

}


tasks.withType<Wrapper> {
    gradleVersion = "8.4"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}


tasks.named<Test>("jvmTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    filter {
    isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
    }
    testLogging {
    showExceptions = true
    showStandardStreams = true
    events = setOf(
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.FAILED,
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.PASSED
    )
    exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to import dependencies in a Kotlin multiplatform project. Please, carefully read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-add-dependencies.html